# EditText with number input only returns 0 as string

Tags: android, android-edittext, gettext, tostring, settext

I have an `EditText` that only accepts numerical input and I am using the following code to turn that input to a string so I can use it later.

```
scoreString = Integer.parseInt(teamScore.getText().toString());
```

The problem is... when I use a setText(), it only says "0" in:

`previewText.setText( scoreString + " :");`

Why won't the integer say what the user put in the edittext?

**EDIT:** If I'm using a `setText` with a ton of strings (6-8 strings in it), will this disrupt the ability to use the number in there?

-I even collected the final chunk of strings and made them into one whole string, THEN used the setText as the `finalOutput` and it didn't work (see below)

```
finalOutput = (sportName + ": " + team1NameString
                    + " " + team1ScoreString + ", " + team2NameString + " "
                    + team2ScoreString + " - " + quarterString + " "
                    + descriptionString);
            generatePreview.setText(finalOutput + "");
```

(sorry I keep changing variable names, just pay attention to the format)

Comment: You might need to trim that String first but I don't remember 100% if that's really necessary: `Integer.parseInt(teamScore.getText().toString().trim())`

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I can confirm the following works the way it sounded like you wanted it to (meaning if I enter "65" in the EditView, it outputs "65 :" in the TextView):

```
    EditText mEditView = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myedittext);
    TextView mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextview);

    int scoreString = Integer.parseInt(mEditView.getText().toString());
    mTextView.setText(scoreString + " :");
```

Is your setup the same?

Comment: The number of Strings shouldn't matter.  I manually set the variables you mentioned/copied your `finalOutput` string in my code and it still worked as expected (it doesn't fit in a comment, but `String team1Name="Team 1"`, `String sportName="Sport"`, etc.).

For debugging purposes, is it all variables or just certain ones that are the problem?  Do your variable types/names match up everywhere?  Did you make sure to do the `findViewByid` after doing the right `setContentView`? It's probably something that's easy to overlook.

Comment: I've double checked everything and I still can't figure out the problem... I have no troubles displaying any strings- its only the number ones that mess up by only returning "0" as the string. I don't have it set as "0" anywhere- I don't know why its displaying that number.

Comment: For testing purposes, what if you just try to echo the entered string itself without setting it to a value? (so `mTextView.setText(mEditView.getText().toString())`).

(Also, is 0 just the value of an uninitialized int in Java?  Try initializing it to 5 and observing the behavior).